# Removing the black box after making text glow in CSS / HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make some of my text glow with CSS. I've been successful in making it glow, however there is now an annoying black box that I cannot seem to get rid of. I simply want it to be transparent, and for there not to be this horrible black box that ruins the effect.

I've attached an image below of the box

[image: The Box]

As you can see, it's almost as-if the background is not transparent. How do I get rid of this box so that the text background is fully transparent?

```css
.heading-secondary {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%; /* 110%; */
  /* font-size: 72px;*/
  background-image: none;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#007CF0, #00DFD8);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 20px #0ff;
}
```

```html
<section class="second-page">
  <div class="our-news">
    <h1 class="heading-secondary">
      Why buy through us?
    </h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If you color the box the text will be nearly invisible. Is that the goal?

Comment: How would I color the box?